# correct way of writing a MySQLi prepared statement in a function?

Tags: php, mysql, coding-style, mysqli, prepared-statement

## Prepared Statements

Okay, I've just started taking a look at MySQLi prepared statements. This was a big step for me as I'm very new to MySQL and PHP anyway, so I have an extremely tenuous grasp on the concept (perhaps about an hours worth), so your answers will have to be phrased similarly, sorry about this.

What I am wanting to know is if I am correctly writing a prepared statement. There's nothing worse than learning a method which is incorrect and getting used to it, therefore coding entire projects inefficiently.

To the point: I have a function which registers a user, and then returns the inserted id, which is therefore the referencing id of the user.

Previously, I was simply querying the database, which I was told had security risks despite the use of `mysql_real_escape_string()` and similar security measures.

Now, it looks something like this: (assume for the sake of this question that all referenced variables are defined, the bound parameters are strings, and all called functions exist and are working).

```
function registerUser($username, $fname, $email, $password, $region, $activation) {
    $uniqueSalt = uniqueSalt();
    $password = sha1($uniqueSalt . $password);

    $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');

    if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('', ?, ?, ?, ?, '$password', '$uniqueSalt', '$activation')") ) {
        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $fname, $email, $region);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo 'error preparing statement';
    }

    return mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
}
```

### Questions

It seems to work, but:

1) Is this correct syntax for executing a prepared statement?

2) I had included the file this function was in (call it function.php) with another file called init.php which previously defined the variable `$mysqli`. I found if I didn't include

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
```

I would receive an error. Why did I have to redefine it inside the function?

3) When I previously ended the function before I used prepped statements, with `return mysql_insert_id()` which worked fine, now I've found I have to use `mysqli_insert_id($mysqli)`.

If I don't include `$mysqli` inside the parentheses I get the error `mysqli_insert_id() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given`. Why is this and why does it differ from what I had before?

Cheers, 
Luke.

Comment: use pdo and you wont have this many problems.

Comment: @Uğur Gümüşhan I have no intentions of dieing due to concept overload. I want to learn a bit about MySQLi first, examine it's differences, and then perhaps examine PDO in a few weeks. But for now, I'm sticking with MySQLi.

Comment: I had the same resistance before, for weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your usage doesn't make a lot of sense. From the [PHP Manual Example](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#example-1593):

   ```
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO CountryLanguage VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
   $stmt->bind_param('sssd', $code, $language, $official, $percent);
   ```

   Compare this to your usage:

   ```
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('', ?, ?, ?, ?, '$password', '$uniqueSalt', '$activation')");
   $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $username, $fname, $email, $region);
   ```

   Notice anything strange? The Manual example is using `?` as a placeholder, where you then use `->bind_param()` to create the substitution set. So your example, I believe, should be:

   ```
   $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` VALUES('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
   $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $username, $fname, $email, $region, $password, $uniqueSalt, $activation);
   ```

   Not knowing if `$activation` is a number or string value. (Also, I would suggest using the column names and not omitting them in the `INSERT` query.)

   Now, what you did should *work* in many cases simply because you're creating a single use statement and using variable expansion to insert the `$pass, $uniqueSalt, $activation` into the query string that is being prepared. Cases where it won't is if you accidentally have a `'` in one or more variables you're putting in the query, which should either be parametized (using `->bind_param()`), or using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. However, mixing these approaches is poor practice and defeats the purpose of using prepared statements. There is no reason to do the first few, but not the last few.
2. Your `$mysqli` variable is ["out of scope"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) when you call it in the function if it's defined globally, hence when not available, you can't use it unless you import it or create another one locally (in the function). You can import it using the `global $mysqli;` syntax within the function (as long as it's created globally and not locally in another function).
3. This is the same issue as #2. See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

My recommendation is to use [PDO](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead of the `mysql_`/`mysqli_` functions.

Comment: Good answer. Thank you. A bit overwhelming but I'll see what I can do with PDO and I'll take your recommendation for now. Thanks again.

Comment: PDO is considered more future-proof and modern than the manual connections of the `mysql_`/`mysqli_` function families. There's nothing wrong with learning/using `mysqli_`, though. Something else you could do is to use a [singleton to get your DB connection object](http://codepad.org/t5kazRsL) instead of a global variable, or to construct a base object that your data classes extend. This is moderately cleaner than using global variables. Note, if you use a function or object constructor, I would also add an error handling method when the DB doesn't connect.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Is this correct syntax for executing a prepared statement?

No, not really. Just look [at the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) which shows you a cleaner way for mysqli, for example not building the string with variables containing values to insert into the database. Next to these probably smaller issues which aren't any for a very good programmer who knows what to do, the syntax is actually correct and as long as the code executes like you want it to execute, then the syntax is correct for executing a prepared statement. Just test on your own and you will know.

> 2) I ...

... have no idea what you're concerned about. Please elaborate clearly and concise. What have you done when, what changed, what happens now? Please add code examples for all the different stages.

> 3) When I previously ended the function before I used prepped statements, with return mysql_insert_id() which worked fine, now I've found I have to use mysqli_insert_id($mysqli)...,

The function `mysql_insert_id` is different from the function `mysqli_insert_id`. Only the same function work exactly the same, so this is nothing special that both functions are different because those are different functions.

Comment: What are these small issues? I can't see any syntactic difference in my statement from the object-oriented example 1 that's presented in the PHP manual page that you linked. How would you code it?